# Precise Digital Temperature Control? & ideas to correctly threshold melt & cool Cocoa Butter for stable Recrystallization at home?

Tags: temperature, cocoa, tempering

Precise Digital Temperature Control? & ideas to correctly threshold melt & cool Cocoa Butter for stable Recrystallization at home?

Trying to look at Hot water dispensers, kettles/ flasks, multi function water / other heating devices and ideas, hacks and techniques around this.

I am not trying to just make chocolate but also better learn how to "handle cocoa butter" in the kitchen - for non chocolate purposes and but as a unique ingredient usable in other recipes as well.

https://www.newfoodmagazine.com/article/74041/an-overview-of-the-crystallinity-of-cocoa-butter/

> Form V
> β2
> 34-35

> Form VI
> β1
> 36

https://www.compoundchem.com/2014/04/19/the-polymorphs-of-chocolate/

[image]
https://www.chemistryviews.org/details/ezine/808827/Chocolate__The_Noblest_Polymorphism_II.html

How to achieve Form V / VI at home?

- Any experiences? Ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: Can't get more precise than this at home: https://modernistpantry.com/products/the-control-freak.html?gclid=CjwKCAjwoduRBhA4EiwACL5RP6CyOIMcbJwBxrLHqyv2LDcjFYhEfunoC0Tte4ovh7tcfuX9jjvYchoC84oQAvD_BwE

Comment: @moscafj - Seems like medical lab equipment turned into kitchen control - as named :)

Comment: Yes, lot's of today's newest kitchen tools were birthed in science labs.